# Relativedelta 28 february and 29 february

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil, relativedelta

I have the following code:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
date_1=datetime.date(2000,2,28)+relativedelta(years=+1)
date_2=datetime.date(2000,2,29)+relativedelta(years=+1)
print(date_1)
print(date_2)
date_1=date_1+relativedelta(years=+1)
date_2=date_2+relativedelta(years=+1)
print(date_1)
print(date_2)
date_1=date_1+relativedelta(years=+1)
date_2=date_2+relativedelta(years=+1)
print(date_1)
print(date_2)
```

And this is the output:

```
2001-02-28
2001-02-28
2002-02-28
2002-02-28
2003-02-28
2003-02-28
```

My question is why the output is the same for both 28 and 29 february?I thought when I enter 29 the answer in the end is gonna be 1/3/2003 and for 28 the answer  in the end is gonna be 28/2/2003.(different answers).Additionally,when I'm doing:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
print(relativedelta(datetime.date(2003,2,28),datetime.date(2000,2,29)).years)
print(relativedelta(datetime.date(2003,2,28),datetime.date(2000,2,28)).years)
```

I get:

```
3
3
```

I don't know why it's the same.

Comment: `date_1=relativedelta(2000/2/29,2003/2/28)` Are you sure that's the actual code?  That's 2000 _divided by_ 2 _divided by_ 29...

Comment: @JohnGordon You're right,I edited the wrong part.